# How to use PDO with codeignitier 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, pdo

Codeignitier shows me just "loaded" from echo, but table is empty when i try to execute this using PDO:

```
function loadCSVtoDB($csvfile){
    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :file
    INTO TABLE `historic` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
    $stmt->bindParam(":file",$csvfile);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'loaded';
    //echo $this->db->conn_id->error_message();
}
```

My database config is:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql:host=localhost',
    'username' => 'zzazfhvsnt',
    'password' => 'censored',
    'database' => 'zzazfhvsnt',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

When i remove **conn_id**, i get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   CI_DB_pdo_mysql_driver::prepare()

Same is when i change exec instead prepare.

I call it like this from constructor:

```
$this->load->model('Historic_model');
$this->Historic_model->loadCSVtoDB("assets/csv/1516E0.csv");
```

In autoload is: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: Using Pdo driver require to change config like this 
`$db['pdo'] = array(
 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=codeigniter',
 //'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'codeigniter',
 'password' => 'codeigniter',
 'database' => 'codeigniter',
 'dbdriver' => 'pdo',`
 difference is that PDO uses dsn rather than hostname; host & dbname are required

Answer (score 0):

Try with code below `'dsn'  => 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=myproject; charset=utf8;',`

Then autoload the database library

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'  => 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=myproject; charset=utf8;',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '*********',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '' ,
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```